# Adding tests to sdist, but not installing

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, testing

I'd like to add tests to the `sdist` package in my `setuptools` distribution, but I don't want them installed / in `bdist`. I already have:

```
setup(
   ...
   packages = find_packages(exclude='tests'),
   test_suite = "tests",
   ...
)
```

But currently the `tests/*` are always included. How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in MANIFEST.in put

```
include tests/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In setup.py :

```
setup(
   ...
   packages = find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
   ...
)
```

Notice the `[]` around `'tests'`.

In MANIFEST.in :

```
recursive-include tests *
```